# Spring SOAP SoapFaultClientException

Tags: java, spring, soap

Everything is working good when I use Postman or SoapUI. But when I try to perform requests programmatically I always getting the error:
`org.springframework.ws.soap.client.SoapFaultClientException: Message part {http://atria.cz/employee/main/position}getEmployeesRequest was not recognized.  (Does it exist in service WSDL?)` here is my class - it was autogenerated by maven-jaxb2-plugin according to https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "getEmployeesRequest", namespace = "http://atria.cz/employee/main/employee", propOrder = {
    "organization"
})
public class GetEmployeesRequest {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String organization;

    public String getOrganization() {
        return organization;
    }

    public void setOrganization(String value) {
        this.organization = value;
    }

}
```

here is my @Configuration:

```
@Configuration
public class EmployeesConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshallerEmployees() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        // this package must match the package in the <generatePackage> specified in
        // pom.xml
        marshaller.setContextPath("com.example.demoSeven.employees.wsdl");
        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public EmployeesClient getEmployeesClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshallerEmployees) {
        EmployeesClient client = new EmployeesClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("https://develop.is-mis.com/employees-ws/service?wsdl");
        client.setMarshaller(marshallerEmployees);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshallerEmployees);
        return client;
    }
}
```

The client code:

```
public class EmployeesClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    private final String url = "https://develop.is-mis.com/employees-ws/service?wsdl";

    public GetEmployeesResponse getEmployeeList(String orgId, String login, String password) {

        String encodeBytes = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((login + ":" + password).getBytes());

        WebServiceMessageCallback callback = new WebServiceMessageCallback() {
            @Override
            public void doWithMessage(WebServiceMessage webServiceMessage) throws IOException, TransformerException {
                TransportContext context = TransportContextHolder.getTransportContext();
                HttpUrlConnection connection = (HttpUrlConnection)context.getConnection();
                connection.addRequestHeader( "Authorization", "Basic " + encodeBytes);
            }
        };

        GetEmployeesRequest request = new GetEmployeesRequest();
        request.setOrganization(orgId);

        JAXBElement<GetEmployeesResponse> response =
                (JAXBElement<GetEmployeesResponse>) getWebServiceTemplate()
                        .marshalSendAndReceive(url, request, callback);
        return response.getValue();

    }
}
```

Call code:

```
public class DemoSevenApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoSevenApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    CommandLineRunner runner(RefsClient refsClient, EmployeesClient employeesClient) {
        return args -> {
            GetEmployeesResponse employeeResponse = employeesClient.getEmployeeList("12345", "Login", "Password");
            employeeResponse.getEmployee().forEach(System.out::println);
        };
    }


}
```

Schema types:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                  xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                  xmlns:tns="http://atria.cz/employee/main"
                  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                  xmlns:pos="http://atria.cz/employee/main/position"
                  xmlns:emp="http://atria.cz/employee/main/employee"
                  xmlns:edu="http://atria.cz/employee/main/education"
                  xmlns:bi="http://atria.cz/common/base/info/build/" name="employeeService" targetNamespace="http://atria.cz/employee/main">
    <wsdl:types>
        <xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
                    xmlns:tns="http://atria.cz/employee/main"
                    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
                    xmlns:pos="http://atria.cz/employee/main/position"
                    xmlns:emp="http://atria.cz/employee/main/employee"
                    xmlns:edu="http://atria.cz/employee/main/education"
                    xmlns:bi="http://atria.cz/common/base/info/build/">

            <xsd:import namespace="http://atria.cz/employee/main/employee" schemaLocation="https://develop.is-mis.com/employees-ws/service?xsd=employee.xsd"/>

            <xsd:import namespace="http://atria.cz/employee/main/position" schemaLocation="https://develop.is-mis.com/employees-ws/service?xsd=position.xsd"/>

            <xsd:import namespace="http://atria.cz/employee/main/education" schemaLocation="https://develop.is-mis.com/employees-ws/service?xsd=education.xsd"/>

            <xsd:import namespace="http://atria.cz/common/base/info/build/" schemaLocation="https://develop.is-mis.com/employees-ws/service?xsd=http://atria.cz/common/base/buildInfo.xsd"/>

        </xsd:schema>
    </wsdl:types>

<!-- ... -->

    <wsdl:message name="getEmployeesRequest">
        <wsdl:part element="emp:getEmployeesRequest" name="request">
        </wsdl:part>
    </wsdl:message>

<!-- ... -->
```

As I understood the type is correct `emp` and  `xmlns:emp="http://atria.cz/employee/main/employee"`  not `position`. So I have no idea why i am getting the error.

Comment: You say the WSDL you use with SoapUI is working for sending requests. Did you use the same WSDL to generate you client code? Unless those imports are messing up the jaxb generation in some way, your generated classes should have the proper namespaces. I suggest you delete the generated classes and generate them again. Annotation says `.../employee` but the message is sent with `.../position`? That's really weird. Clean project and recompile. Try to also loge the SOAP message that's going out, maybe you get some clues from there also...

Comment: @Bogdan I tried to delete and create classes many times without any effect. Also the wsdl service is out of my control. But maybe you are right, maybe it is worth to change the class a little bit. Actually I tried to call wsdl via simple ```HttpClient``` and it is working well.